# NSTimer crashes, when I call [Timer isValid] or [Timer invalidate]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, crash, nstimer

I have two NSTimers in my iPhone app.
DecreaseTimer works fine, but TimerCountSeconds crashes when I call [timerCountSeconds isValid] or [timerCountSeconds invalidate]. They are used like this:

```
-(id)initialize { //Gets called, when the app launches and when a UIButton is pressed
 if ([timerCountSeconds isValid]) {
  [timerCountSeconds invalidate];
 } 
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { //Gets called, when you begin touching the screen
 //....
 if ([decreaseTimer isValid]) {
   [decreaseTimer invalidate];
  }
 timerCountSeconds = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(runTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 //....
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {//Gets called, when you stop touching the screen(not if you press the UIButton for -(id)initialize)
 //...
 decreaseTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(decrease) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 //...
}
-(void)comept3 { //Gets calles when you rubbed the screen a bit
    if ([timerCountSeconds isValid]) {
    [timerCountSeconds invalidate];
    }
}
```

What did I do wrong?
Can you please help me?

Comment: have you initialised TimerCountSeconds and DecreaseTimer?

Comment: I declared them in the header file... I initialised them in "touchesEnded" and "touchesBegan" methods

Comment: Show more code. Also, having names like `DecreaseTimer` for instance variables is generally a very bad idea. Names that begin with an uppercase letter are used for classes and structs. Consider using a consistent style that Apple advocates.

Comment: okay, I changed the variable names... I forgot to enter the "comept3" method... this will probably help you to help me ;)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should set an `NSTimer` object to `nil` after you `invalidate` it, since the `invalidate` method call also does a `release` (as per the Apple docs). If you don't, calling a method on it like `isValid` could cause your crash.

Comment: Douple up-vote - searched for this problem for hours... Btw.: It may be *very* sensible to retain the NSTimer if it is checked elsewhere with isValid. If not retained, it may be auto-released when fired (also see the answer from Chuck).

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the timer stored in that variable has already been deallocated. You need to retain it if you want to keep it around for an arbitrarily long time.

Comment: when will it be deallocated? so when do I have to retain it?

Comment: It will be deallocated when the runloop decides it can be deallocated. If you want to keep it around, you should retain it when you store it somewhere, as with any other object.

Comment: okay I think I understood ;) I retained it after the initialisation... now it does not crash any more:) is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

```
 [objTimer retain];
```

Then it will not crash any time. Use this after initializing the timer so it will work fine....

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the timer in main thread. NSTimer will not be fired in background thread.

- Objc:

  ```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:delay target:self selector:@selector(YOUR_METHOD) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
  });
  ```
- Swift:

  ```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
     timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(delay, target: self, selector: "YOUR_METHOD", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
  }
  ```

Comment: What about invalidate(). Do I need to call it in main thread also?

Comment: Yes, invalidate() also has to be in main thread

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually initialise the `TimerCountSeconds` and `DecreaseTimer` members in initialise.  Assuming you're control flow is:

```
...
myObject = [[MyObject alloc] initialize];
...
[myObject touchesBegan:...]
...
[myObject touchesEnded:...]
...
```

Then when you call `initialize` `TimerCountSeconds` has not been initialised, so you're logically doing

```
[<random pointer> isValid]
```

Which will crash.  Similarly DecreaseTimer is invalid the first time you call touchesBegan.

In your initialise method you will need to actually initialise everything, before you attempt to use anything.

You also appear to be leaking timers (`touchesBegin` invalidates the timer but does not release it)

Comment: If these are instance variables, they are not "random pointers" — they're nil.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)StopScanTimer
{
    if(scanTimer != nil)
    {
        [scanTimer invalidate];
        scanTimer = nil;
    }
}

-(void)StartScanTimer
{
    [self StopScanTimer];

    float duration = 10.0f;
    scanTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:duration target:self     selector:@selector(OnScanTimerElapsed) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:scanTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    [scanTimer retain];
}

-(void) OnScanTimerElapsed
{
    // Do something
}
```

If you remove "[scanTimer retain];", it will crash when you call invalidate.
Always retain the timer if you want to use it back.