# NSTimer: is invalidate called when it is released?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimer, nsrunloop

I have a class which has an NSTimer, when I release it, does invalidate also called? Or can I do them both in dealloc:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [_timer invalidate];
    [_timer release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

I read in this thread:

[invalidate method call also does a release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692359/nstimer-crashes-when-i-call-timer-isvalid-or-timer-invalidate)

the picked answer says invalidate method also does a release, so I do not need to release it if I invalidate it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sending `release` to an `NSTimer` won't invalidate it.

If the `NSTimer` is scheduled in a run loop, then the run loop retains the timer.  So even when you release the (scheduled) timer, it still has a retain count larger than zero.  Also, it will keep firing.  If the timer's target has been deallocated, the app will probably crash when the timer fires.

When you send `invalidate` to a scheduled timer, the run loop releases the timer.

If the `NSTimer` is not scheduled in a run loop, then it doesn't need to be invalidated.  But it's safe to send `invalidate` to a timer whether it's scheduled, not scheduled, or already invalidated.

So you should send your timer `invalidate` in your `dealloc` method, unless you're sure it's already been invalidated.

If you created the timer using `[[NSTimer alloc] initWith...]`, then you should also release it.  But if you created the timer using `[NSTimer timerWith...]` or `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWith...]`, you should *not* release it, because you don't own a reference to it.

Comment: so is it true that invalidate will also release it?

Comment: Whether `invalidate` releases the timer is irrelevant.  That's a private implementation detail.  *You* need to release it *if* you own a reference to it.  Read *[Cocoa Core Competencies: Memory management](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html)*.

Comment: Excellent answer, this really tripped me up back when I was a beginner +1.